# how to get the product of all odd numbers up to n using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to get the product of all odd numbers up to n. But the output is always 0.

```sh
read -p "Enter a number: " n

prod=0

for((k=1; k<=n; k++))
do
    if [ k%1==0 ]
    then
        prod=$((prod*=k))
    fi
done

echo "Product of odd counting numbers until $n is $prod"
```

Comment: I have removed the [tag:sh] tag: this uses multiple Bashisms (`read -p`, C-style for loop)

Answer (score 2):

Modulo operation is superfluous for this task. Just use a C style `for` loop with increments of 2:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter a number: " n
prod=1
for ((k = 3; k <= n; k += 2)); do ((prod *= k)); done
echo "Product of odd counting numbers until $n is $prod"
```

Be aware that the product will overflow easily. For example, on a 64-bit system, when `n` is equal to or greater than 35. If you want the correct result for greater `n`s, you may want to use the `bc` utility:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter a number: " n
prod=1
for ((k = 3; k <= n; k += 2)); do prod+="*$k"; done
printf "Product of odd counting numbers until %d is " "$n"
bc <<< "$prod"
```

Notice that, in this context, `prod+="*$k"` is string concatenation, not an arithmetic operation.

Answer (score 0):

Any arithmetic expressions need to be in $((..)) and so:

```
read -p "Enter a number: " n
prod=0
for((k=1; k<=n; k++))
do 
  if [[ "$((k%1))" == "0" ]]
  then
    prod=$((prod*=k))
  fi
done
echo "Product of odd counting numbers until $n is $prod"
```

Answer (score 0):

Four problems:

- `[ k%1==0 ]` means "is the string `k%1==0` non-empty?" And it always is, so this will always be true.

  - You need blanks around the operator, and `==` is only allowed in Bash, but not Posix compliant.
  - `k%1` is just a string; you need an arithmetic context to do math.

  Together, this would be

  ```sh
  if [ $((k%1)) = 0 ]; then
  ```

  but can be replaced in Bash with

  ```sh
  if ((k%1 == 0)); then
  ```
- There's a logic bug: to determine if a number is odd, you have to check it modulo 2; modulo 1 is always 0:

  ```sh
  if ((k%2 == 1)); then
  ```

  which can be shortened to

  ```sh
  if ((k%2); then
  ```

  because a non-zero result in `((...))` is truthy
- `prod=$((prod*=k))` has a redundant assignment: you can use

  ```sh
  ((prod *= k))
  ```

  on its own
- You have to start with `prod=1`, or it will always stay 0

Combined, fixing all ShellCheck complaints:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -rp "Enter a number: " n
prod=1

for ((k = 1; k <= n; ++k)); do
    ((k % 2)) && ((prod *= k))
done

echo "Product of odd counting numbers until $n is $prod"
```